# Laravel 5 How to perform validation in Controller to check for specific data in data collection

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5

I want to perform custom validation in laravel 5, here is the concept. I have a category controller in which i want to delete a particular category. If category contains any other sub category i want to show validation error in laravel 5. For this concept i have create the program, but the program does not perform required validation. I am getting varies error like valiable not found or validation not performing or Undefined variable: struct. Below is the code that i am using to do that.

```
CategroyController destroy function, to delete record.

public function destroy(Request $request)
    {
        if(\Request::ajax()){
            $validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), array());
            $data = Configuration::findTreeParent($request->input('id'), 'Category');
            $selected = $request->input('id');
            foreach($data as $struct) {
                $validator->after(function($validator) {
                    if ($selected == $struct->id) {
                        $validator->errors()->add('field', $request->input('configname').' cannot be assigned to its child category.');
                    }
                });
            }
            if ($validator->fails()) {
                return $validator->errors()->all();
            } else{
                return \Response::json(['response' => 200,'msg' => $validator->fails()]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Please look into and help me out from this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `closure` you need to pass a variable to its `scope` before using it. In your case `$struct` is not available in the scope of the closure you are passing to `$validator->after()`.

So basically you have to pass the `$struct` to the closure.

```
// you can remove this line. $selected = $request->input('id');
$validator->after(function($validator) use ($struct) {
   if ($request->input('id') == $struct->id) {
      $validator->errors()->add('field', $request->input('configname').' cannot be assigned to its child category.');
   }
});
```

To return the JSON response for the validation errors, update the following ode.

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
    return \Response::json($validator->errors()->all(), 422);
}
```

Read about closure [here](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

Comment: That's working, But the result is return as status code 200. It should be returned as ajax error.

Comment: Its because you are passing 200 status code in your response. Update it to be 422. 422 status code is the right one for validation.

Comment: No i am not passing any status code. Can you check above. I have simply check whether validation failed or not. If failed that return all error otherwise return json output.

Comment: `return \Response::json(['response' => 200,'msg' => $validator->fails()]);` notice the `response => 200`?. Update that to 422 or whatever you want.

Comment: okies. You need to return `\Response::json($validator->errors()->all())`. Or whatever format you want the error to be.

Comment: also why are you returning `$validator->fails()` when there is no error? Arent you meant to be returning the data or something?

Comment: I tried your updated code, But it does not returning any message and the status code still 200.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please put more effort in debugging and see why its failing. In you case $selected is null inside the clousure as we didnt pass it in. I have updated the answer and also pass the status code as second parameter.

Comment: I have changed it to return new \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse($validator->errors()->all(), 422); and its magically start working. Thanks buddy.